# React Router OnEnter hook called twice

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

I'm having a pretty straightforward case. I want to redirect customer loading my index page to /dashboard or /login based on whether they're logged in or not. The problem is, onEnter handler is being called twice every time and I wonder why. Here's my code:

```
ReactDOM.render(
<div>
    <Provider store={ store }>
    <Router history={ history }>
        <Route path="/" component={ App }>
            <IndexRoute onEnter={ requireAuth }/>
            <Route path="/login" component={ Login } />
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={ Dashboard } />
        </Route>
    </Router>
    </Provider>
</div>,
document.getElementById('root'));
```

And here's an alternative version. The problem exists both ways.

```
ReactDOM.render(
<div>
    <Provider store={ store }>
    <Router history={ history }>
        <Route path="/" component={ App }>
            <IndexRedirect to="/counter" />
            <Route path="/login" component={ Login } />
            <Route path="/counter" component={ Counter } onEnter={ requireAuth } />
        </Route>
    </Router>
    </Provider>
</div>,
document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I;m not sure if it solves your problem but maybe try to wrap each component in HOC which checks if user is authenticated and display proper component or redirect to another... But if you want to use onEnter I will try to investigate it.

Comment: put `onEnter` method on the App component.

Answer (score 3):

I found the reason. It is a bug in react-router-redux v4.0.7. There is an issue logged [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux/issues/481). Till a fix is merged, a downgrade to v4.0.6 fixes it.

Answer (score -1):

Try refactoring your routes likes this

```
<Provider store={ store }>
    <Router history={ history }>
        <Route path="/" component={ App }>
            <IndexRedirect to="counter" />
            <Route path="login" component={ Login } />
            <Route path="counter" component={ Counter } onEnter={ requireAuth } />
        </Route>
    </Router>
 </Provider>
```

I think route `/counter` calling again your `App` component and then again asking for `onEnter`.